# How to update crontab for a non-root user on Solaris non-interactively?

Tags: solaris, cron, rpm, specfile

I would like to update crontab entries for a non-root user for an application which gets installed as OpenPKG RPM package.

Currently I have this in the `%post` section of my .spec file:

```
#
# Set up the 'app' user's crontab.
# Marker lines are used to separate content from different packages:
#     #Begin of App package
#     # ...
#     #End of App package
# Replace any possibly existing content between these lines and insert the
# content of the installed new file
CRONTAB=/var/spool/cron/crontabs/%{V_user}
if [ -f $CRONTAB ]; then
    begin=`head -1 %{V_instdir}/etc/crontab`
    end=`tail -1 %{V_instdir}/etc/crontab`
    if [ -z "$begin" ] || [ -z "$end" ]; then
        echo "Error: Start or end delimiter line is empty. Check '%{V_instdir}/etc/crontab'"
        exit 1
    fi
    sed -e "/^$begin/,/^$end/d" $CRONTAB > $CRONTAB.tmp
    cat %{V_instdir}/etc/crontab >> $CRONTAB.tmp
    mv $CRONTAB.tmp $CRONTAB
else
    cp %{V_instdir}/etc/crontab $CRONTAB
fi
chown root:sys $CRONTAB
chmod 600 $CRONTAB
```

This does not work: The file is created correctly, but `cron` does not pick up the changes. I suppose it is not allowed to edit the file in `/var/spool/cron` directly.

What is the right way to edit the crontab?

- The `crontab` man page doesn’t mention a way to load a crontab for a user from a file. It doesn’t accept one from standard input.
- Can I signal the `cron` daemon to re-read the crontab files?
- Or should I use `su`, along the lines of

  ```
  su %{V_user} -c "crontab -l > $tmpfile"
  # Make the changes
  su %{V_user} -c "crontab $tmpfile"
  ```

  Wouldn’t this fail if the target user does not have permissions to edit his own crontab file?

The OS is Solaris 10. I don’t have root access. Someone else has to install the RPM package I create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, cron(1M) doesn't accept any signals to reread crontabs. The way the crontab(1) tool communicates with cron is through interprocess communication (see the [source](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/cron/funcs.c#cron_sendmsg)). That said, it seems that crontab is probably the best tool you could use to modify a user's crontab. You could write a script that adds/deletes/modifies the crontab and use it as follows:

```
EDITOR=<your script> crontab -e <user>
```

The script takes one argument, a name of the file that holds a copy of that user's crontab, processes the file, and exits with return code 0. crontab then will signal cron that a user's crontab has changed. In case you end up with an empty crontab, though, you have to change strategies and use

```
crontab -r <user>
```

instead. A bit annoying.

The other possibility would be to just restart cron after your modification with

```
svcadm restart cron
```

but that requires su or at least the solaris.smf.manage.cron right.

Comment: Thanks for your help. (Ab)using the EDITOR variable was the key. I went with making the changes as in the snippet in my question and then issuing `EDITOR=touch crontab -e <user>`. Seems to work well.